# What is the Custom Class in Storyboard builder used for?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development.
I saw a few tutorials and examples editing the `Custom Class` in the `Identity Inspectors`, but they did not mention why they did this.

What is it actually doing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for when you subclass an element used in the storyboard - the class you use is the one that will be initialized.

Example: When creating a custom `UITableViewCell` with various `IBOutlets` defined in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, you need to somehow associate the layout you created in the interface builder with the class itself. This is how it's done.